# Web service disconnection from client

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have created a web service which i have deployed on IIS .If my web server got disconnected from network then my client should give immediate exception when i will try to call any web service function.

But it is not giving me any error immediately. It gives me web exception after a period of time.

It is a problematic issue for me.

Comment: The only way you'd know there's a problem, is when you actually call the web service. If its taking too long to return (with exception or without), you could set a shorter timeout period.

Comment: if i m using proxy like service1 obj=new service1(); obj.Timeout will set for all function.